# Alocação dinâmica em C

Tags: c

Estou fazendo uma base de um jogo da forca.

Eu estava tentando fazer um vetor dinâmico mas não está funcionando, ele retorna um erro:

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char *palavras;
    char p[200], x;
    int cont,i;

    palavras = NULL;
    while (x!='S' && x!='s'){
        printf("\ndigite a palavra a ser inserida no jogo da forca: ");
        scanf("%s",p);
        cont++;
        palavras = (char *)realloc(palavras, sizeof(int)*cont);
        palavras[cont-1] = (char*)p;
        printf("Deseja sair? <S:N>: ");
        scanf("%s",&x); 
    }
    printf("saiu\n"); 
    printf("%s",p);
    for (i=0;i<cont;i++){
        printf("%s",palavras[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que quer fazer? Este código não faz sentido. Se fizer algo que faça sentido este erro desaparece.

Answer (score 3):

O primeiro problema que vejo no seu código é que `x` não está sendo inicializado. Logo, ao testar no `while` se o valor é diferente `s` ou `S`, o resultado é que o comportamento inicial é indefinido. Isso é fácil de resolver, basta inicializar com `n`.

O segundo problema é que usar `scanf` com `%s` sem especificar o tamnho máximo é equivalente a usar um `gets`. A solução é especificar o tamanho máximo com `%199s`. Outra opção é usar `char p[201]` e `%200s`. Note que o buffer tem que ser pelo menos um byte maior que o tamanho máximo do `scanf` para que o terminador nulo da string possa também ser armazenado.

Um terceiro problema é que o `scanf("%s", &x);` deveria ser apenas `scanf("%c", &x);`. Pois aqui você só quer ler um caractere.

Um quarto problema é que você verifica se `x` tem o valor `S` ou `s` que você considera como "Sim" e considera qualquer outra coisa como "Não" quando deveria ser apenas `N` e `n`.

Mas o grande problema é no ponteiro `palavras`. Aparentemente você não entendeu o conceito de ponteiro e confundiu várias coisas. Um ponteiro para caracteres (`char *`) pode apontar para um endereço que é o início de uma sequência de caracteres. Isso é algo bem diferente do que a lista de palavras que você está tentando criar.

Quando você acessa `palavras[i]`, uma vez que palavras é do tipo `char *`, você vai estar acessando a letra na posição `i` de uma só palavra dada por esse ponteiro. Isso é bem diferente da sua ideia de acessar a palavra na posição `i` da lista.

Como você está acessando uma sequência de caracteres pensando tratar-se de uma lista de palavras, o resultado é um erro de compilação, pois os tipos de dados esperados pelo compilador não estão corretos.

Há vários jeitos diferentes de se implementar uma lista de palavras. De cara, penso em três formas de fazer isso:

1. Listas alocadas dinamicamente de tipos estruturados onde cada nó tem o endereço de uma string.
2. Ponteiro para ponteiro de caractere.
3. Array de ponteiros de caracteres.

Vamos usar a abordagem 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct NODO_PALAVRA {
    char *conteudo;
    struct NODO_PALAVRA *proxima;
} NODO_PALAVRA;

typedef struct LISTA_PALAVRA {
    struct NODO_PALAVRA *primeira;
    struct NODO_PALAVRA *ultima;
} LISTA_PALAVRA;

void adicionar_palavra(LISTA_PALAVRA *lista, char *palavra) {
    NODO_PALAVRA *novo = (NODO_PALAVRA *) malloc(sizeof(NODO_PALAVRA));
    novo->proxima = NULL;
    novo->conteudo = (char *) malloc(201);
    strcpy(novo->conteudo, palavra);
    if (lista->primeira == NULL) {
        lista->primeira = novo;
        lista->ultima = novo;
    } else {
        lista->ultima->proxima = novo;
        lista->ultima = novo;
    }
}

void limpar_lista(LISTA_PALAVRA *lista) {
    while (lista->primeira) {
        NODO_PALAVRA *n = lista->primeira;
        lista->primeira = lista->primeira->proxima;
        free(n);
    }
    lista->ultima = NULL;
}

void mostrar_lista(LISTA_PALAVRA *lista) {
    NODO_PALAVRA *n;
    for (n = lista->primeira; n; n = n->proxima) {
        printf("%s\n", n->conteudo);
    }
}

int main() {
    char p[201], x = 'n';

    LISTA_PALAVRA palavras;
    palavras.primeira = NULL;
    palavras.ultima = NULL;

    while (x != 'S' && x != 's') {
        printf("\nDigite a palavra a ser inserida no jogo da forca: ");
        scanf("%200s", p);
        adicionar_palavra(&palavras, p);
        x = 'u';
        while (x != 's' && x != 'n' && x != 'S' && x != 'N') {
            printf("Deseja sair (S | N)? ");
            scanf("%c", &x);
       }
    }

    printf("Saiu\n");
    mostrar_lista(&palavras);
    limpar_lista(&palavras);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```